# Excluding folders in karma.js with phantomjs and angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a problem when I try to run karma tests with phantomjs if I have some examples with another node_modules inside.

For instance:

```
MyComponent
└── node_modules
└── examples
    └── node_modules
    └── src
        └── app
            └── app.component.ts
            └── app.component.html
            └── app.component.css
            └── app.component.spec
            └── app.module.ts
        └── assets
        └── index.html
        └── angular-cli.json
        └── karma.conf.js
        └── package.json
└── src
    └── app
        └── my.component.ts
        └── my.component.html
        └── my.component.css
        └── my.component.spec.ts
    └── assets
    └── base.spec.ts
    └── karma.conf.js
    └── package.json
```

**package.json**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
    "@types/core-js": "0.9.36",
    "@types/echarts": "0.0.5",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.1",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "echarts": "3.4.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.44",
    "@types/node": "6.0.65",
    "typescript": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "karma": "1.5.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-typescript": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "karma-typescript-angular2-transform": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4"
  }
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({

        frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript"],

        files: [
            { pattern: "base.spec.ts" },
            { pattern: "src/app/**/*.+(ts|html)" }
        ],

        exclude: [
            'examples/**/*.js',
            'examples/**/*.ts'
        ],

        preprocessors: {
            "**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
        },

        karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            bundlerOptions: {
                entrypoints: /\.spec\.ts$/,
                transforms: [
                    require("karma-typescript-angular2-transform")
                ]
            },
            coverageOptions: {
                instrumentation: true
            }
        },

        reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],

        browsers: ["Chrome"]
    });
};
```

When I run the tests without the examples folder, everything works, but If I try to run the tests with the examples inside and ignore it it does not work.

I get the next error:

> 14 03 2017 11:15:07.881:ERROR [karma]: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'name' of undefined
>       at mergeSymbol (/workspace/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:25122:46)
>       at /workspace/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:25146:21
>       at Map.forEach (native)

Answer (score 0):

I found thee mistake.

I have to exclude the folder inside preprocessor config:

`karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            bundlerOptions: {
                entrypoints: /\.spec\.ts$/,
                transforms: [
                    require("karma-typescript-angular2-transform")
                ]
            },
            coverageOptions: {
                instrumentation: true
            },
            exclude: ['examples']
        },`